# File ownership appears to change to logged in user

Tags: macos, permission, file-sharing

I'd appreciate it if anyone can shed light on this file ownership bizarreness on my server.  Googling has revealed no answers.

I have a MacMini home server.  On this machine /Pierson is a mounted FireWire drive, shared to other household machines using Mac OS X File Sharing.

The problem: everyone who can SSH into the server thinks the files and folders under the shared drive are owned by them.  I can't restrict some folders for use by particular users using Unix file permissions:

Sam thinks the folders are owned by "sam":

```
$ ssh sam@server
$ id
uid=10000(sam) # etc...
$ ls -ld /Pierson/Movies
drwxrwxr-x  6 sam  staff  204 Oct 21 20:41 /Pierson/Movies/
```

John this the files and folders are owned by "john":

```
$ ssh john@server
$ id
uid=10001(john) # etc...
$ ls -ld /Pierson/Movies
drwxrwxr-x  6 john  staff 204 Oct 21 20:41 /Pierson/Movies
```

Now I expect this kind of behavior if connecting to the shared folder remotely, but having things change from under me on the server is a problem.

This machine was originally a Lion Server, later upgraded to Mavericks.

Comment: Did you have the same *thingy* when running Lion?

Comment: What filesystem is the removable drive (`mount` on its own will tell you)? That could very well have a bearing on the ownership...

Comment: @mjturner It is HFS.  Hmm interesting, mount says "noowners".  I need to research what that means: `/dev/disk1s2 on /Pierson (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
`

Comment: That was is! The noowners mount option ignores all ownership on the volume.  You can disable that by doing Get Info -> Sharing and Permissions -> Ignore ownership on this volume (uncheck).  As described here: http://mac-os-x.10953.n7.nabble.com/Help-with-quot-Noowners-quot-on-mount-td15051.html.